# Should the presenter access view data via properties or event parameters?

Tags: mvc, mvp

I have a new-employee form.

When the "Save" button is pressed, a `SavingRequested` event is raised. The Presenter gets an `Employee` object from the View and passes it to the Model for further processing.

Should the `Employee` object created by the View be passed to the `Presenter` via the event arguments:

```
public event EventHandler<SavingRequestedEventArgs> SavingRequested;
private void OnSavingRequested()
{
    SavingRequested?.Invoke(this, new SavingRequestedEventArgs(employeeObject);
}
```

or should the View have an `Employee` property that the Presenter will access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event data approach will keep you a little closer to the [observer pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ObserverPattern), but you should probably not create (or instantiate) `Employee` from within the view. It's almost like you're directly coupling the view with the model [as explained here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148377/in-an-mvc-architecture-how-closely-coupled-are-the-model-and-view-to-the-contro).

Find a bare data structure that supports properties, and pass that to the Presenter (controller?) instead via a regular object

Comment: Thanks. Why shouldn't the View get access to the domain objects?

Comment: There's a lot of articles on the subject, but generally you'll end up with a view layer that's easier to maintain, test and reuse.

Comment: Thanks. I asked a new question about this topic so you could elaborate if you wish: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361064/in-mvp-should-the-view-have-access-to-domain-objects